Mui-x datepicker ddd dd format not updating
I have tested this in the playground that MUI-X gives themselves and can be reproduced there, as well.
If I use ddd dd-MMM-YYYY as the format and type in a date, the ddd does not getupdated.
Fri 11-Aug-2023
If I change 11 to 12, it doesn’t update Fri to Sat. I see the value change in the dayjs property. If I type in
Fri 12-Aug-23 and press Tab. It updates to Sat 12-Aug-2023! Buggy? Weird? Yes. Buggy, well kinda?
Does anyone have any clue how to get this working properly?
Edit: I used an useEffect to set the value of the input (inputRef on the Datepicker).
This changes the value but afterwards Datepicker changes it back to the wrong value. Weird stuff

Not a proper fix, more a hack.
In the slotProps -> textField -> InputProps -> startAdornments
There I placed my own weekday component that updates the week day, the datepicker gets the format without the ddd, so the user doesn’t know any better. Not ideal
